# Get multiple values in a single column / row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, subquery, sql-server-2016

I have a table `projects` in which I have projectid and projectname.
Each project has multiple users and the table is `project_users` and the fields are `projectuserid, projectid`.

Also each  project has multiple solutions and the table is `project_solutions` and the fields are `projectsolutionid, projectid`.

Again each solution has multiple users these are stored in the table `solution_users` and the fields are `solutionuserid, solutionid, userid`

There are master tables here `users` for users with fields `userid, username` and `solutions` for solutions with fields `solutionid, solutionname`.

I am trying to get the output in single row where the first column will be `projectid` and second column is the respective `users of the project in an array or json format` the third is `solutions for the project` and the fourth is `solution users`

The tables are as below

### projects

```
 projectid      projectname
    1             abc
    2             xyz
```

### users

```
 userid      username        image(data type image)
    1          user1         04949949499994
    2          user2         3434jj34kjd3434
    3          user3         8934u34kj343434
```

### solutions

```
 solutionid      solution_name
     1               sol1
     2               sol2
     3               sol3
```

### project_users

```
  id     projectuserid        projectid
   1           1                  1
   2           2                  1
   3           3                  2
```

### project_solutions

```
 id            solutionid       projectid
  1                1                1
  2                3                1
  3                2                2
```

### project_solution_users

```
  id       projectsolutionid         userid
   1             1                      1
   2             1                      2
   3             2                      1
   4             2                      2
   5             2                      3
```

The output which I am expecting is like below

```
 {
  projectid:1
  users: [user1, user2],
  solutions: [ sol1, sol3 ],
  user_images: [04949949499994, 3434jj34kjd3434]
 }
 {
  projectid:2
  users: [user3],
  solutions: [ sol2 ],
  user_images: [04949949499994, 3434jj34kjd3434, 8934u34kj343434]
  }
```

This is what I tried

```
    select p.projectid, ps.solutionid, cast(cast (uu.image as varbinary) as varbinary) as userimage,
    from projects as p
    left join project_users as pu on pu.projectid = p.projectid
    left join users as u on u.userid = su.userid
    left join project_solutions as ps on ps.projectid = p.projectid
    left join solutions as s on s.solutionid = ps.solutionid
    left join project_solution_users as su on su.projectsolutionid = ps.solutionid
    left join users as uu on uu.userid = su.userid
    group by p.projectid, s.solution_name, cast(cast (uu.image as varbinary) as varbinary)
    for json path, without_array_wrapper
```

But it generates multiple rows.

How can I achieve this using SQL Server? I have tried using inner joins and sub queries but I got stuck and not getting the respective output.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using ?. Since SQL Server 2016 you can directly get your output in JSON.

Comment: @MarcGuillot yes it is 2016. Could you please help me with the query

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Comment: @MitchWheat Could you please help me out with the query. I am new to SQL and I am not understanding how to build this. It seems to be complex for me

Comment: Show what you tried. See [ask], [help], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @philipxy I cant as it is in my client server. Also what I tried will not help

Comment: Please do not ask us to do your homework. Show what parts you can do & some part that you are stuck in. Code questions without a [mre] get closed (blocked from answers). Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy I added the query which I tried in my question above

Comment: Try like this @Saisri... SELECT  P.ProjectId,PP.Projectuserid
FROM [dbo].[Project] P
INNER JOIN Project_Users PP
ON P.ProjectId = PP.ProjectId
FOR JSON AUTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  t1.projectid,
        username,
        user_image,
        solution_name
from    dbo.project_solutions t1
left join dbo.project_users t2 on t2.projectid = t1.projectid
left join dbo.users t3 on t3.userid = t2.projectuserid
left join dbo.solutions t4 on t4.solutionid = t1.solutionid
for json auto
```

Comment: with the above query I didnt get everthing in a single row but I used "for json auto" along with subqueries